Could a software patent be used against the inventor of the algorithm?
Since in practice algorithms can actually be patented, sometimes I wonder if it is possible for example for a company to take a open-source code I wrote and released and somehow file a patent for its algorithm and use that patent to send a cease-and-desist against me.
or does the fact that my code was published before the patent already grants enough protection?

united-states
If someone obtains a valid patent, this patent may be enforced against anyone, even the person who was really the true original inventor of the patented invention who for some reason failed to obtain the patent for that invention.
The fact that the U.S. Patent and Trademark office issues a patent makes the patent presumptively valid. But this presumption is not a bar to the affirmative defense of an alleged patent infringer that the patent is invalid. This defense is often raised and is often successful.
Duly issued patents are invalidated at trial or on appeal is about half of all litigated patent infringement cases. (This statistic is a number of years old and may partially reflect previously lax USPTO standards for granting business methods patents. In 2001, 45% of business method patent applications were granted. In 2004, the grant percentage had dropped to 11%. It also reflects that fact that clearly valid patent infringement claims are usually settled prior to a trial and prior to any dispositive motion in a patent infringement case. But it is certainly still true that patent invalidity is still raised in a majority of litigated patent infringement cases and that this defense is often successful. For example, in August of 2017, the U.S. Court of Appeals for the Federal Circuit invalidated a patent claim on the concept of podcasting. The problems caused by USPTO grants of dubious patents is discussed, e.g., in the book "Patent Failure: How Judges, Bureaucrats, and Lawyers Put Innovators at Risk," by James Bessen and Michael J. Meurer (Princeton Univ. Press, 2008).)
If the allegedly infringed claims in the patented invention are part of previously published software, the U.S. PTO issued patent can be defeated on the grounds that the allegedly infringed claims in the patented inventions were prior art. And, someone other than a true inventor of the invention can't avail themselves of any limited exception to the prior art rule.
As the prior inventor who published open source software, you would be in a good position to easily prove that the patent you are alleged to have infringed is prior art.
On the other hand, suppose that both you and the person who ultimately obtained the patent independently came up with the invention, but you tried to protected your idea as a trade secret through non-disclosure agreements with your software customers (who had no way to access the black box code that contains the invention), while the other person sought and obtained a patent. Since your invention wasn't published, the fact that you came up with the idea and were using it first wouldn't constitute prior art that could bar someone else from patenting it. So, you could lose a patent infringement case in that situation even if you were the first to come up with and use the invention.

I wonder if it is possible for example for a company to take a
open-source code I wrote and released and somehow file a patent for
its algorithm and use that patent to send a cease-and-desist against
me.

This could certainly happen and it does happen.
Lots of patents that don't hold up under strict scrutiny in court still get issued by the U.S. PTO. And, patent infringement cases are very expensive to litigate for both the plaintiff and the defendant. Usually, a patent infringement case will require expensive expert witness testimony on both sides, and while not all patent litigation has to be handled by a U.S. PTO registered patent lawyer, lawyers who litigate patent infringement cases usually bill at hourly rates that are well above average for litigation attorneys. And, while lawyers will sometimes agree to take patent infringement cases on a contingent fee basis, this is usually not an option for someone defending a patent infringement case. It would be rare for attorney fees, expert witness fees, and other out of pocket litigation expenses in a patent infringement case that is litigated to trial to be less than $100,000 on an hourly attorney fee basis, and litigation costs up to $350,000 to do so wouldn't be particularly remarkable.
So, if you are faced with a cease and desist letter based upon an invalid patent, there is a good chance that you will have to come up with a large dollar retainer (often, mid-five figures) to fight that claim in court  knowing that it could take years for the case to finish, that you are unlikely to get an attorney-fee award in your favor even if you win, and that the outcome of your case in the courts is never certain. Insurance against the risk that you will be sued for patent infringement is hard to find and prohibitively expensive to obtain for someone in your shoes.
As a result, you may be under intense pressure to settle a bogus cease and desist letter on unfavorable terms because you are unable to mount your defense in a cost-effective way, or because you simply don't have the money to fight the case, even if you can be as efficient about it as it is possible to be in the federal courts where these cases are litigated.
The one saving grace you may benefit from if you are sued for patent infringement in connection with open source software is that there is a decent chance that a non-profit or private attorney could be convinced to take on your case for free, i.e. on a pro bono basis.
Big businesses that invent things on a regular basis mitigate this risk by having a patent attorney on retainer to monitor all applications for patents in their business area, and challenging these patent applications before they are issued. But this is a prohibitively expensive approach for an individual inventor or software writer who has only his or her own ideas as intellectual property, rather than the intellectual property of a large group of inventors in a company.
